# How to upload file in R when the name changes everyday

Tags: r, excel, dynamic, upload, filenames

I have a file that needs to be uploaded each day, file name `MIS_01_10062022.xlsx`. Each day `MIS_01_` part of the file name is constant the date part - `10062022` changes due to date. How can I upload this file with out selecting it each day? Is it possible to select file by just mentioning the file name as `MIS_01_*`.

Comment: Have a folder with the target file to send in it. Once sent the original is deleted. When a new file is posted in the folder that triggers a new send & delete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy of what you could try:

- List all the in the directory that might be of interest, e.g. via `a<-list.files(pattern="MIS_01_")`
- Save all file informations (e.g. when the files were created) in a second variable, e.g. via `b<-file.info(a)`
- Find the latest file using the "mtime" column of this dataframe, e.g. via `latest_file_index<-which.max(b$mtime)` . This will return the index of the newest file, which you can again access in your initial variable a, via `latest_file_name<-a[latest_file_index]`